# HttpServletRequestObject is null

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, tomcat7

i had to complete a project that was 60% done already. I completed it and it works. But i cannot seem to understand why this part of the code is implemented. We are using Spring MVC and this method comes under a controller. The mapping works,functionality works. But i would like to know why should we check if the request and response objects are null. Under what conditions can they be null? I have searched for answers but unable to find them. Would love some clarity.

```
    @RequestMapping("/newVistor.htm")
public ModelAndView newVisitor(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    if (request == null || response == null) {
        log.info("Request or Response failed for NEWVISITOR METHOD..");
        throw new FERSGenericException(
                "Error in Transaction, Please re-Try. for more information check Logfile in C:\\FERSLOG folder",
                new NullPointerException());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects are created & managed by servlet container (Tomcat, Weblogic, etc..), so they will NOT be `null`, unless you are managing them in a different way.

So, you don't need to do the above `null` checks for these `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects.

**HttpServletRequest API:**

> The servlet container creates an HttpServletRequest object and passes
>   it as an argument to the servlet's service methods (doGet, doPost,
>   etc).

**HttpServletResponse API:**

> The servlet container creates an HttpServletResponse object and passes
>   it as an argument to the servlet's service methods (doGet, doPost,
>   etc).

You can look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html)